# Combine two commands into a single command

Tags: bash, scripts, filename

I'm looking for a way to combine these two so I can do it in one step from the command line. (I think `%1` would be in the command.)

```bsh
convert Tess.jpg tess.tif
tesseract tess.tif tess
```

For example:

```bsh
text2file name of scanned document
```

This is on Ubuntu MATE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You indicated that you want to be able to run

```bash
text2file name-of-scanned-document
```

to have the effect of the two commands:

```bash
convert Tess.jpg tess.tif
tesseract tess.tif tess
```

In that case, you're looking to write a simple script, or to define a shell function. You mentioned that you thought what you wrote might contain `%1`. That's how a Windows (and before that, DOS) batch file would use the first command-line argument passed to it, but in Bash the [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters) are instead `${1}`, `${2}`, and so forth<sup>1</sup> (with the `{` `}` braces optional below `${10}`). So you would write `$1`, not `%1`.

---

To make a shell script, create a file with the name you want for the command (`text2file`), with these contents:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
convert "$1.jpg" "$1.tiff"
tesseract "$1.tiff" "$1"
```

`$1` expands to the first command-line argument passed to the script. This may contain spaces, just make sure to enclose it in quotes when you run the script. The [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) around `$1` in the script itself are to prevent undesired [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (which are further expansions that otherwise would be performed on the result of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

If you want the `tesseract` command to run only if `convert` succeeds, then you can place a `&&` after the `convert` command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
convert "$1.jpg" "$1.tiff" &&
tesseract "$1.tiff" "$1"
```

`&&` must not be *preceded* by a newline, but it may be followed by one *if you like*, or you can remove the newline just after it as shown in [Giiba's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250112/22949). That is, the technique shown there is entirely correct (though it's not presented in the context of writing a script).

(`&&` one of the two most popular ways to achieve that. The other is `set -e`, which in this case would work fine but which can be [remarkably non-intuitive in some of its effects](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).)

Then mark your script executable by running:

```bash
chmod +x text2file
```

You can then run the script using a path to it that contains at least one `/`. So from the same directory in which the script resides:

```bash
./text2file name-of-scanned-document
```

To be able to run it as `text2file`, and from anywhere, put the file in a directory listed in your `$PATH` environment variable. I recommend `~/bin` (i.e., the `bin` directory located directly inside your home directory). If this directory doesn't exist, you can create it. On all subsequent logins, it will be added to `$PATH` automatically, since `~/.profile` contains code that checks if `~/bin` exists and prepends it to `$PATH` if it does.

Then you would run:

```bash
text2file name-of-scanned-document
```

For the example you gave, that's just:

```bash
text2file tess
```

`$1` expands to `tess` when it is run that way, so you should not (and in fact must not) write a file-type suffix after `tess` when you run it. Here's an example of how you'd run it when the name, `two words`, contains whitespace:

```bash
text2file 'two words'
```

---

If instead you'd prefer to implement `text2file` as a shell function, you can put this definition at the bottom of `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
text2file() {
    convert "$1.jpg" "$1.tiff"
    tesseract "$1.tiff" "$1"
}
```

Or:

```bsh
text2file() {
    convert "$1.jpg" "$1.tiff" &&
    tesseract "$1.tiff" "$1"
}
```

Then in all your subsequently started interactive Bash shells, it will be available. If you want to use it in a shell that's already started, you could source `~/.bashrc` (`. ~/.bashrc`), or you could directly run that function definition (i.e., the code shown above) in the shell.

When using an interactive Bash shell, you would run it exactly the same way as if you wrote it as a script and put it in a directory in your `$PATH`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically the positional parameters are *themselves* `1` (not `$1` or `${1}`), `2` (not `$2` or `${2}`), and so forth. Likewise, you technically have no `$PATH` environment variable, as the environment variable is called `PATH`. Unlike in some languages (e.g., Perl, PowerShell), the leading `$` (and subsequent enclosing `{` `}`, if present) is not really part of a parameter or variable name, but is instead the syntax used to trigger parameter expansion.

Comment: I had to run the script with the .sh extension for it to run. @Eliah Kagan

Comment: I'm glad it works! That's strange, though. In Ubuntu, the script shouldn't need or benefit from an `.sh` suffix. The only situation in Ubuntu where I'd expect that is if you have a WSL Ubuntu system in Windows 10 and you're running the script from Windows Explorer, *and* Windows has file associations set up for `.sh` so that it is run by `bash` in the WSL system. (It's okay to apply an `.sh` suffix to an executable script, but such a suffix is more appropriate for a *library*, i.e., a non-executable intended for *sourcing*, directly or indirectly, by a script, via the `.` or `source` builtin.)

Comment: I like the .sh because it shows clearly that it is a bash script. @Eliah Kagan

Answer (score 3):

you can use && to join terminal commands:

```
<command 1> && <command 2> && <command 3>
```

So if I understand correct you want to:

```
convert tess.jpg tess.tif && tesseract tess.tif tess
```

Comment: Your method works, but it only works with a fixed name.

Answer (score 1):

Building a simple bash script would likely be the best option. Here are some good examples of where to start.

[TLDP.org](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html)
[Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/writing-simple-bash-script/)

Take a look specifically at the Linux.com variable sections. You dont even need to build a function, just chain the commands with a variable so you can make the script more extensible and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose another solution.

```
convert Tess.jpg tif:- | tesseract stdin tess
```

This avoids creating the intermediate file tess.tif whatsoever.
Instead it pipes the output from the `convert` directly to the `tesseract`.

This has some advantages:

1. You don't pollute the directory with intermediate files,
2. You don't do unnecessary writes to your hard drive,
3. It might be slightly faster.

Many command line tools are able to output to stdout/input from stdin instead of using files. For those `convert` and `tesseract` I found how to do this in their respective `man` pages.

It can be made into command as mentioned by other by:

1. Creating a shell script:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > text2file
echo 'convert "$1.jpg" tif:- | tesseract stdin "$1"' >> text2file
chmod +x text2file
./text2file tess
```

Those commands will create a script in the current directory, so it will be accessible like that only in the current directory. To make it accessible in any directory you would need to move it to `~/.local/bin` eg. by using command `mv text2file ~/.local/bin`.
Afterwards it may be used in any directory like:

```
text2file tess
```

2. Creating a bash function

```
echo 'text2file() {' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'convert "$1.jpg" tif:- | tesseract stdin "$1"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '}' >> ~/.bashrc
```

It won't be accessible right away. You would need to reload the .bashrc configuration with `source ~/.bashrc` or by just opening the new terminal.

Comment: ./text2file tess I have found that using the .sh extension allows the script to be run with just textfile.sh Another advantage of using the .sh extension is that allows creation of a thunar custom action that adds the executable attribute. @Dluzaki

Comment: andy@7_~/Downloads$ ls
bookms.html  Denon1.jpg  Denon2.jpg  NewSongsForCarCD
andy@7_~/Downloads$ text2file.sh Denon1
/home/andy/bin/text2file.sh: 2: /home/andy/bin/text2file.sh: convert "$1.jpg" tif:- | tesseract stdin "$1": not found